# Would meta be a good place to ask for a update on old question

Tags: discussion, support

Would meta be a good place to ask for an update on an old question?

Example:

> Is there anyone from India that could update this question on electronic payment methods, I am sure there has been some progress made...
>
> [What are some electronic payment systems available for use by foreigners in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83395/what-are-some-electronic-payment-systems-available-for-use-by-foreigners-in-indi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meta is usually not a good place to ask for an update on old question because meta participants are generally fewer than the main sites.

Putting a bounty with "Current answers are outdated" reason is the feature that Stack Exchange has provided for this specific case, just like what JonathanReez has done on [the linked question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83395).

Otherwise, you can also share the question to friends/social media/etc asking if they have more updated info and let them post the answer there!

Answer (score 3):

I think an edit to the question and a comment with the request is more likely to be seen by people who can answer the question.

If you happen to know anybody out of the country or who have been to the country recently and meet them in Chat, you can ask there.
Not just the travel chat but also those other chats that allow off topic chatting.